# Twilio Voice api order of calling url and statusCallback with machine detection enabled

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

While making twilio calls, we have a `url` and a `statusCallback` parameter like this:

```
client.calls
  .create({
     method: 'GET',
     statusCallback: 'https://www.myapp.com/events',
     statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
     statusCallbackEvent: ['completed', 'answered'],
     url: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
     to: '+14155551212',
     from: '+18668675310'
   })
  .then(call => console.log(call.sid))
  .done();
```

(From [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls#call-end-setting-your-statuscallback) )

I am having a hard time figuring out whether the `url` is called before the `statusCallback` or vice versa?

I see that when `machineDetection` is enabled in a call (as given [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection)) if `Answered_by` is `machine_start` then the `statusCallback` is called **before** the `url` (that supplies the twiml).

While in one case I found out that if `machineDetection` enabled and `Answered_by` was `human` (ie. it detected a human picking up the call), I saw the `url` called first.

So what is the expected order of invoking `url` and `statusCallback`? (Assuming that I have setup `statusCallback` to be called for an in progress call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From the [documentation on calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call), here's some other detail about the `statusCallback`:

> A URL that Twilio will send asynchronous webhook requests to on every call event specified in the StatusCallbackEvent parameter. If no event is specified, Twilio will send *completed* by default.

The `StatusCallbackEvent` parameter can be set to any or multiple of initiated, ringing, answered, and completed.

Since you don't have an event setup, you are using the default `completed` event. This event should be fired once the call is over. If you are seeing it fire before your URL is called, are you using other events?

The other thing is that these events are fired asynchronously to the call. Even if the `ringing` event is fired, by the time your web server responds to it, the call may be over. So I would program defensively for the state of the call, not assume that the call is definitely in progress.

More clearly: The events fire asynchronously, so you cannot guarantee that the `answered` callback will be fired before or after the `url` param is fetched.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have setup `completed` and `answered` events. Just updated my answer. 

My question would be more about the `url` param that fetches the `twiml`. When is it supposed to fire? (Before or after statusCallback url?)

Comment: The events fire asynchronously, so you cannot guarantee that the `answered` callback will be fired before or after the `url` param is fetched.

Comment: ok thanks man! This really helped a lot!! I think it would be worth putthing this comment in your answer IMO